# displaying all form field names but checkbox's and radios fields dont show

Tags: php

i have an html form full of text fields, checkbox's , and radio fields.
i wanted to get all the names of the fields so that i can get started in validating the information in them.

the method i am using to get them is

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    print $name."<br/>";
    }
}
```

but i noticed that it only displays textbox and textarea field names and it doesnt include checkbox and radio field names through this submission. do i need to include anything for it to grab the field names of those?

Comment: its huge let me see ill put it online

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a valid question.  Please comment when down-voting to let the OP know your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes and radio buttons work a little differently than your standard inputs.  If a checkbox is present on a form that doesn't necessarily mean that it will be available in the resulting POST information.  Rather, those values will only be avialable if they are actually marked (checkboxes checked and radio buttons selected).  The proper way to test for their value in PHP is not to check the field value but rather to check `isset()` first.

For a checkbox:

```
$data['my_checkbox'] = isset($_POST['my_checkbox']) ? 'on' : 'off';
```

and for a radio button:

```
$data['my_radio'] = isset($_POST['my_radio']) ? $_POST['my_radio'] : false;
```

---

To be a little more descriptive let's say you have the following form:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="active" value="Yes" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If I were to submit that form with an email value of 'test@email.com' but **not** check the checkbox I would have the following in $_POST:

```
Array (
  'email' => 'test@email.com'
)
```

However, if I were to submit the same form with the same email address **and** check the checkbox I would have the following:

```
Array (
  'email' => 'test@email.com',
  'active' => 'Yes'
)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

0./ Try using the following code to see the raw posted data:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

1./ Make sure you use a name attribute value for your checkbox and radio inputs.

Typically for checkboxes, it will be an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" id"=fruit-apple" name="fruits[]" value="apple" />
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit-pear" name="fruits[]" value="pears" />
```

2./ Make sure they sit inside the `form` tag.

3./ If you submit using a javascript call, try disabling javascript and see if the error stays. If it does not, you know your javascript is the culprit.